# ROS and DOCKER installation?

Tags: ros, installation, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Can someone clarify my doubt regarding ROS & Docker installation ?
My doubt is that whether we have to install first ROS on Ubuntu and then Docker in ROS environment OR we have to install first Docker on Ubuntu and then ROS on it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254085/ros-and-docker-installation-?/) by [a443](https://answers.ros.org/users/29219/a443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2017-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both are possible, but only one order of installation (ROS *in* your Docker image) would seem to make sense (or at least: would allow you to exploit the isolation that Docker containers provide).

If you want to run nodes in a Docker container, then install Docker, create an image that install ROS (or use one of the [osrf/ros](https://hub.docker.com/r/osrf/ros/) images) and then start containers from those images.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; First Docker, then ROS into it.

(Update: Oh - old question - bummer)

If your goal is to install ROS or ROS 2 on the supported OS or Ubuntu version, then you do not need Docker at all - (although a Docker containerized ROS or ROS 2 installation is possible, just not needed for most applications.)

If your goal is to install ROS or ROS 2 on a different OS or OS version than the officially supported - e.g. I wanted to install ROS 2 Humble on a Raspberry Pi 5 running the Raspberry PiOS 64-bit Desktop Bookworm, then installing Docker, "pulling a ROS Dockerfile" and letting Docker build the desired version of ROS | ROS 2 (with a minimal supported OS version) is the easiest way to get ROS on any Docker-supported OS.

Links are discouraged here so I will list the titles of my shell scripts for installing Docker and subsequently ROS 2 derived primarily from reading the official docs.ros.org sections on installing "Dockerized" ROS:

1_setup_docker_apt_repo.sh
2_install_docker_packages.sh
3_clone_ros_docker_images.sh
4_build_humble_desktop_container.sh
5_test_humble_desktop_container.md
6_build_humble_desktop_plus_container.sh

Following the official procedure gets ROS or ROS 2 running on your machine, but my robot needed nav2 and slam-toolbox, so I had to create a Dockerfile that told the Docker builder how to extend the desktop image to include everything I needed.

So your question "My doubt is that whether we have to install first ROS on Ubuntu and then Docker in ROS environment OR we have to install first Docker on Ubuntu and then ROS on it." - First Docker, then ROS into it.

[Here is the link to my scripts](https://github.com/slowrunner/pi5desk/tree/main/configs/docker)